# Kivy buttons have white line on x and y axis

Tags: python, button, kivy

when I try to create buttons I get white lines on x and y axis (depending if the width or height is too low - if both then there is line on both of the axis)

[image: White lines over buttons]

```
label_height = 30
label_width = 100
```

```
 Button(text="Don't reset",
        size_hint=(None, None),
        size=(self.label_width, self.label_height),
        background_normal="",
        background_color=(1, .2, .2, .4)
        )
```

I've tried to play around with the setting(fonts, background, size,..) and the only thing that seems to work is just to increase x or y then it dissepears. If there is no text it still appears.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a line under the button. Because you set alpha to .4 it is visible. Try to change alpha to 1 and check if line is still visible:

```
background_color=(1, .2, .2, 1)
```

Comment: Nice. It seems to solve the problem! Thank you very much. I'm still not sure what was the issue though.. because I dont have any lines in canvas. But anyway thank you.

Comment: It looks similar to line above the buttons. Without complete kv file it's hard to quess where the line comes from.